# What is the best tool for labelling pictures?

Tags: images, machine-learning

I am looking for a tool for labeling images. What I need to do is load in a large dataset of faces, and compare whether one image is older then the other, or the same age. I want to do this manually, and a tool that would place the two images side by side and allow me to chose one of the two. Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: I was at an Exhibition recently where they had a camera with a face recognition system running nonstop, tracking visitors, inviting visitors to play with the system. Depending on head-camera distance, lighting, cutout, head rotation/tilt, facial expression etc the system estimated my age continuously: between 33 and 56. So do not expect great accuracy.

Comment: Specifying operating system would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [digikam](https://www.digikam.org/) might be useful here.

It has the side by side view, it has face recognition tagging, and it has generic tagging.

Answer (score 0):

[Kairos](https://www.kairos.com/) is one of the better online face recognition tools but unless the face images are taken in a highly reproducible fashion (such as are specified for passport photos) results for matching rather than detection may be disappointing. If the aim is to estimate the age of the subject, I'm not sure if they offer that but they do estimate emotion. If the image date is in the metadata (date modified or date taken) then the comparison can be done with many tools